# React emotion styled not working but normal css was working fine for input and label styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, emotion-js

Everything is working except this piece which I have tried many different ways...

```
    const HiddenInput = styled.input`
    display: none;
    &:checked + CheckboxLabel: {
        background-color: #866dce;
    },
`
```

The checked should change color but it doesn't. I also tried using .checkbox-label where classname='checkbox-label" but no luck

Here is the relevant code...

```
const CheckboxLabel = styled.label`
    background-color: rgb(211, 106, 106);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
`
const HiddenInput = styled.input`
    display: none;
    &:checked + .checkbox-label: {
        background-color: #866dce;
    }
`

<HiddenInput type="checkbox" id={"toggle"+index} onChange={() => handleChecked(item)} key={"input" + index} />
<CheckboxLabel htmlFor={"toggle"+index} className="checkbox-label" key={"label" + index}>{item}</CheckboxLabel><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap the component with `${}`. Also there's a scss syntax error, you had to remove `:` from the front of your selection element:

```
    const HiddenInput = styled.input`
      display: none;
      &:checked + ${CheckboxLabel} {
        background-color: #866dce;
      },
`
```

note: you can use babel-macro that's included by default in create-react-app

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled/macro'
```

[image: emotions]

Comment: I tried this but I get this error...    Uncaught Error: Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with babel-plugin-emotion. I think this is for a different import. mine is import styled from '@emotion/styled'

Comment: @JustinOberte https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/babel-plugin I think you are missing from your dependencies. But if you update to version 8 it should work fine

Comment: https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#targeting-another-emotion-component

Comment: Hmm I installed the plugin but I am still getting the same error

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.1.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "plotly.js": "^1.58.4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },

Comment: it is in my devDependencies but I still get the error.

Comment: can you try `import styled from '@emotion/styled/macro`

Comment: Well, that resolved the error but it is back to square one. The label still doesn't change when checked.

Comment: So this is weird. &:hover worked but &:checked did not. I think this is a checkbox issue in emotion styles? When I remove the "display: none" I see checkboxes but when I click them they do not check. This is probably the issue.

Comment: I created a simple sandbox with your code (only hardcoding some values)

Comment: Ah I got it! One of my styled elements was in the function returning to the dom and it didn't like that. Oh my goodness. What a headache that was. Thank you so much for the help. This resolves it.

Comment: If you are still around... How would I pass props into this style if it has to be declared outside of my functional component? For some reason when I declare it inside my function, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: i updated the sanbox passing a color props where the default is white fwiw. you need to pass as a function `${props => logic here}`

Comment: but what if my props are determined in the main app function as your example is laid out? How would I use those props? It is strange because in other parts or my program I am able to declare the style inside the function everywhere except for this case and I do not know why. I think I need this in order to pass props from the same function. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh man. Nevermind. I think I have had too much coffee. This one was obvious. Thanks again for the help